# Error: You called Tooltipster's "show" method on an uninitialized element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have implement Tooltipster'splugin in my scroll anchor link, its working but also generating some error in console

**Error: You called Tooltipster's "show" method on an uninitialized element**

[image]

http://pastebin.com/qpRiqEfj

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from the developer
have look

https://github.com/iamceege/tooltipster/issues/511